# Express res.json({}) not sending data to angular application

Tags: node.js, express, angular7

I am trying to pass res.json after reading folder size. I am not receiving data in angular front-end. Below is the code for reference-

```
 const items = fs.readdirSync('//prod_storage1/shared/Computer_Ops/public/Users/');

      for(let folderperm of items){
       fs.access('//prod_storage1/shared/Computer_Ops/public/Users/'+folderperm,fs.constants.R_OK , (err) => {
         if (!err) {
           countFiles++
         } 
       });
      }
    let prom = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      items.forEach(function(folder){
        try {
          
          getSize('//prod_storage1/shared/Computer_Ops/public/Users/'+folder,async (err, size) => {
            c++
            //&& size > 314572800
            if (!err ) { 
              try {
                  fullName = await ad.user(folder).get()
              } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error)
              } 
              counter++
              folderArr.push({fullName:fullName.cn,folderName:folder,size:(size / 1024 /1024 /1024 ).toFixed(2)})
              
              console.log(counter+'- '+fullName.cn+'~ '+folder+' : '+size);
              if(folderArr.length == countFiles){
                console.log('done')
                let folderSize = folderArr;
                folderSize.sort(function(a, b){return b.size-a.size});
                resolve(folderSize)
                
              }     
            }else{
              console.log(countFiles)
              console.log(c+'...'+folder)
            }
          })
        } catch (error) {
        
        console.log(error)
        }
      })
    })
    let finalRes = await prom;
    console.log(finalRes)
    res.status(204).send({'size':finalRes})
    console.log(res.headersSent)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the status to 200 it should work. Status 204 is "No content", so it does not send back the JSON.

```
res.status(204).send({value: something})
```

becomes

```
res.status(200).send({value: something})
```

which is the same as

```
res.send({value: something})
```

Comment: Tried, res.status(200).json({value: data}). Not getting back the JSON still.
I am using npm get-folder-size as getsize. 
    -https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-folder-size

Comment: I noticed that the promise is not resolved if it goes through the other branch of the if statement. Are you seeing the debug lines at the end with the correct data?

seems like there should be a resolve for this section:
      else{
              console.log(countFiles)
              console.log(c+'...'+folder)
            }

in the case there is an err it is not null, the promise is neither resolved nor rejected. Is it just hanging on an error?

Comment: I am receiving result in console.log(finalRes),also console.log(res.headersSent) shows true. Data is not receiving in front-end.

Comment: Have you tried testing your API directly with Postman,  CURL, a web browser or another means to confirm that it is your API is not returning the data?  https://www.postman.com/ I usually test my APIs fist with Postman, and once I confirm they are working correctly, then I try to call from my client code.

Comment: What output do you get when you call `curl http://0.0.0.0:3001/your-path` ?